# What is the method to reference another opened workbook which is in a separate window?

Tags: excel, vba

I could open another workbook in separate window by using two methods

```
TheEmu_Path = "excel.exe " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "myexcel.xlsx" 
call Shell(TheEmu_Path, 3)
```

or

```
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
oExcel.Workbooks.Open Filename:=TheEmu_Path & "myexcel.xlsx"
```

The first method I could Open but don't know how to set a reference for the open workbook
The second I could reference when opening the workbook but later for any later process I don't know how to reference that separately-opened worksheet

```
Set oExcel = ??
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks("myexcel.xlsx")
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("F1")
```

How can I set the reference for oExcel (the already separately opened workbook)?

After creating and opening, later I want to change value in that open separately workbook in new button command

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks("myexcel.xlsx")
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("1")
oWS.Cells(1, 1) = 55
```

I have a mistake in line two as I believe that I still haven't referenced oExcel correctly.

---

### Comment on David revision

Impressive, thanks a lot.

It works perfectly with very little addition, oExcel will be considered as workbook directly - great!

```
Dim oExcel As Object 'or Dim oExcel As Workbook
Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet 'or Dim oWS As Worksheet

Set oExcel = GetObject(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "myexcel.xlsx").Application
'or Set oExcel = GetObject(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "myexcel.xlsx")

Set oWS = oExcel.Sheets("1")
oWS.Cells(1, 1) = 4
```

This is exciting and encouraging to ask other question as I have my file crashes when using UpdateRemoteReferences that result in #na values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new instance of Excel:

```
Dim oExcel as Excel.Application 'or As New Excel.Application
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
'Dim oExcel as Object
'Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Alternative method for late-binding
```

When I do this, a new Excel opens, and there is one blank workbook file.  To reference this workbook:

```
Dim oWB as Workbook
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks(1)
```

To open a file within this instance:

```
Dim anotherWB as Workbook
Set anotherWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\test.xlsx")
```

Etc.

Although I don't usually recommend working with multiple instances of the application, I just don't have any use to do this, I just open all workbooks in one instance of Excel.Application.

**Updated per comments requests**

The easiest way to control multiple instances, IMO, is to start with a clean slate and create new objects, controlling them during runtime, per examples above.

In cases where this is not possible, it is still possible to get the other instance.  In both cases I think you will need to know the name of an open workbook file in the other instance of Excel.

**Easier**

If you know the workbook name, you can get access like:

```
Dim oExcel As Object ' or Excel.Application
Set oExcel = GetObject("Workbook_Name.xlsx").Application
```

You can then refer to workbooks using the ordinary methods, as long as you qualify that you're working with `oExcel`, e.g.:

```
Dim otherWorkbook as Workbook
Set otherWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks(1) 'or oExcel.Workbooks("Workbook_Name.xlsx")
```

**More difficult, possibly more versatile**

Another option is to use the WinAPI functions to get the windows handle.  I have used the WinAPI to do things like this before, and although I have not tested the example code below, it should be a good place to start.

http://excelribbon.tips.net/T009452_Finding_Other_Instances_of_Excel_in_a_Macro.html

Comment: Thanks david , it is not clear in one point, Later binding,lets consider it's already opened seperatly,I ttried below but got error in the second row  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks("myexcel.xlsx")
        Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("1")
        oWS.Cells(1, 1) = 55

Comment: I need the seperate instance to section my screen and some other need for working with more than one monitor.

Comment: See revision for two possible options you can try :)